# Application not shown on Add/remove list of other users

Tags: .net, uninstallation

The application is developed by VS.Net 2008 with .net framework 3.5. Install package is created by using the installation project of VS.net 2008.

If you log in with a different user, the application is not shown on the add/remove list. So basically there's no way to uninstall it unless you log in using the user account who installed it.

Any insight about this problem?

NOTE:It's not a user right problem, since two users are system admins.

Answer (score 0):

In wix, to generate a package that installs to all users you include this snippet.

```
<!-- Force the install to all users, rather than just the current user -->
<Property Id="ALLUSERS">
  <![CDATA[1]]>
</Property>
```

Whilst I don't use VS Setup projects so can't point you to the specific area I'd recommend some investigation into how to do the same in VS.

**Updated:**  This link shows you how to set the property InstallAllUsers in vs setup project.
[http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58021-deploying-a-c%23-application-visual-studio-setup-project/](http://Deploying%20a%20C#%20application)

Comment: Thanks. There's a InstallAllUsers property for the VS setup projects. I tested on a sample application and it solved the problem.